# SSRS empty value for sparkline

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I created an SSRS report to show results of data received/loaded for the last 12 months.  There are 3 data sources and 2 of them have data populated for the entire 12 months as expected.  One of the Data Source has data populated for only the first 6 months, not the last 6.  The trend line/sparkline is accurate for the 2 of the data sources but not for the 3rd where there is a drop off.  I want to add a sparkline which shows the dropoff when the counts go from 999,999 to 0.

**Example:** 
[Click here to see report issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCX21.png)

**Note:** there is no data in the DB, so the results for the last cpl months or so never appear in the results set.

I need to update Data Source 1 to accurately reflect the last couple of months as 0.

Please help.

Comment: In the value field for the sparkline use the expression     =IIF(Isnothing(fields!sparklinevalue.value),0, fields!sparklinevalue.value) if you have the Month Field for the null columns populated this will work. Otherwise change your Query to always pull the MonthField for the values even if the value is null and use the expression above.

Comment: The easiest way to overcome such issues is to fix your dataset to return 0 instead of null.. meaning.. do a cross join to a data table and then aggregate your data so for each month a minimum of 0 is returned.